# Scrapy webscraping an overwatch profile page

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, portia

I'm very new to python, and coding in general. I'm trying to make a webcrawler that scrapes the data from an overwatch player page (eg: https://playoverwatch.com/en-gb/career/pc/eu/Taimou-2526)
I tried using portia, and it worked in the cloud, but I couldn't get it working when I exported it as scrapy code.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APqfG.pnghttps://i.stack.imgur.com/APqfG.png) is a screenshot of my portia spider.

Here is the code of my spider (exported from portia as scrapy): owData.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import



   #!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import absolute_import

from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import Identity
from scrapy.spiders import Rule

from utils.spiders import BasePortiaSpider
from utils.starturls import FeedGenerator, FragmentGenerator
from utils.processors import Item, Field, Text, Number, Price, Date, Url
(Image, Regex)
from items import PortiaItem


class Owdata(BasePortiaSpider):

    name = 'owData'
    allowed_domains = [u'playoverwatch.com']
    start_urls = \
        [u'https://playoverwatch.com/en-gb/career/pc/eu/Taimou-2526']
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), deny='.*'),
             callback='parse_item', follow=True)]


items = [[]]
```

And here is my items.py code:

```
 from __future__ import absolute_import

import scrapy
from collections import defaultdict
from scrapy.loader.processors import Join, MapCompose, Identity
from w3lib.html import remove_tags
from .utils.processors import Text, Number, Price, Date, Url, Image


class PortiaItem(scrapy.Item):
    fields = defaultdict(
    lambda: scrapy.Field(
        input_processor=Identity(),
        output_processor=Identity()
    )
)

def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    self._values[key] = value

def __repr__(self):
    data = str(self)
    if not data:
        return '%s' % self.__class__.__name__
    return '%s(%s)' % (self.__class__.__name__, data)

def __str__(self):
    if not self._values:
        return ''
    string = super(PortiaItem, self).__repr__()
    return string


class CareerOverviewOverwatch1Item(PortiaItem):
field1 = scrapy.Field(
    input_processor=Text(),
    output_processor=Join(),
)
melee_final_blows = scrapy.Field(
    input_processor=Text(),
    output_processor=Join(),
)
table = scrapy.Field(
    input_processor=Text(),
    output_processor=Join(),
)
tr = scrapy.Field(
    input_processor=Text(),
    output_processor=Join(),
```

when I run my spider using:

```
scrapy crawl owData -o data.csv
```

I just get an empty data.csv file.
I'm guessing there's something wrong with my items?
I think the xPath line should just be //tbody, but again, I know nothing about Python, xPath or scrapy...

Comment: Could you reformat owData.py and items.py with the correct indentation under the class definitions? In Python, leading whitespace matters, and could make or break your code.

Comment: Have you tried some debugging? Use some prints inside the fuction calls to see what you're getting and if there's a specific place where it's not working.

Comment: @SunnyPatel I accidentally removed the indentation in my post, but it should be correct in my original files.

Comment: @GeorgeRappel thanks for your comment, but as I said, i know nothing about python :) , I was hoping that by downloading my Portia spider, everything would work fine.

Comment: In that case, i would recommend learning about Python and how it works first. Especially if you are new to programming as a whole. There are several books and websites that can ease you in to overall understanding of the syntax, debugging, etc. Once you're comfortable with the basics, you'll be much better off!

Comment: I see a reference (by string) to a `parse_item` method, but I do not see that method in your code.